# How can I avoid repeating messages in vr_ad?

Tags: specman, e

In my environment I see too many messages coming from the vr_ad.  typical "disturbing" example:

Three consecutive messages, all informing of one access – reading from address 0x5

[14] C_BUS: (info - Fetch) Fetch EX_CBUS_MAP vr_ad_map-@1, address: 0x00000005
[14] C_BUS: (info - Fetch) Fetch XCORE vr_ad_reg_file-@2, address: 0x00000005
[14] C_BUS: (info - Fetch) Fetch EX_PROXY_REG vr_ad_reg-@7 in XCORE vr_ad_reg_file-@2, addr 0x00000005, data 0x00000008

Why are there so many messages?
And how can I remove these messages?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you work with verbosity MEDIUM or even higher. To reduce amount of messages, you can change verbosity to LOW (and then you will see only the last message - the one from the vr_ad_reg, and not from its containers), or even to NONE - and then you will get only critical messages.

To change verbosity - you can use either the set message command, or message_manager api. (the messages configuration is per instance - so you can have different vr_ad messages verbosity for each sub-environment)

For example -

```
specman>set message sys.env.sub_env1 -tag=VR_AD_MSG HIGH
```

or

```
extend my_env {
    post_generate() is also {
        message_manager.set_screen_messages(me,
                                            VR_AD_MSG,
                                            FULL);
    };
};
```

Another thing you might want to do is filtering message based on "direction" - different setting for update, fetch, and compare_and_update.
For example - to avoid getting messages that come after write (vr_ad update() ), but see messages coming from compare_and_update() -

```
vr_ad remove update messages
vr_ad add compare messages
```